# Hover providers in case of multiple monaco editors

Tags: monaco-editor

I have built a component `ResizableMonacoEditor` on top of Monaco Editor. In `index.tsx`, we have

```js
import * as monaco from 'monaco-editor';
const MonacoEditor = lazy(() => import('react-monaco-editor'));

monaco.languages.register({ id: "mySpecialLanguage", extensions: [], aliases: [], mimetypes: [], });

class ResizableMonacoEditor extends React.Component {

  _handleEditorDidMount(editor, monaco) {
      ... ...
      monaco.languages.registerHoverProvider("mySpecialLanguage", {
        provideHover: (model, position, token) => {
            return {
                range: new monaco.Range(1, 1, model.getLineCount(), model.getLineMaxColumn(model.getLineCount())),
                contents: [
                    { value: '**SOURCE**' }
                ]
            };
        }
    });
  }
  ... ...
  render() {
    return <MonacoEditor {...this.props} editorDidMount={this._handleEditorDidMount.bind(this)} />
  }
}
```

It works when we have only 1 `ResizableMonacoEditor` on a page. Now, I would like to have two `ResizableMonacoEditor` on a page. They are all supposed to hold programs in `mySpecialLangauge`.

Then, I realize that each editor registers one hoverProvider. As a consequence, when I hover on a text in one editor, two `**SOURCE**` are shown in the message. But, I think only the hoverProvider registered by the editor should be executed.

Does anyone know what is the correct way to organize language, editor, model, and registerHoverProvider in case of multiple monaco editors?